# WPF C# Manage events from different class with windows components

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, wpf-controls

I would like to create a personal component with different windows elements . For simplicity here, just one label and three radiobtn. For now I decide to create a simple new class that not extend other.

```
    class BoxActionPlayer
    {

        public StackPanel stkPanel { get; set; }
        Label lbl;
        RadioButton rdBtn1;
        RadioButton rdBtn2;
        RadioButton rdBtn3;
        RadioButton rdBtn4;

        public BoxActionPlayer(string actionPlayer)
        {
            InitializeComponent(actionPlayer);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent(string actionPlayer)
        {
            stkPanel = new StackPanel();
            lbl = new Label();
            rdBtn1 = new RadioButton();
            rdBtn2 = new RadioButton();
            rdBtn3 = new RadioButton();



            lbl.Content = actionPlayer;
            rdBtn1.Content = "Fold";
            rdBtn2.Content = "Check";
            rdBtn3.Content = "Call";
            stkPanel.Children.Add(lbl);
            stkPanel.Children.Add(rdBtn1);
            stkPanel.Children.Add(rdBtn2);
            stkPanel.Children.Add(rdBtn3);
            stkPanel.Children.Add(rdBtn4);
             
            //there how i manage event of rdBtn1,rdBtn2,rdBtn3 ??
           //but i need information in other class
        }
    }
```

Now how i can manage the event ? If i use this class in MainWindow like this :

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        GameStart game;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            game = new GameStart();
            InitializeComponent();
            startGame();

        }

        #region private routine


        private void startGame()
        {
             //some stuff here..
             //on main windows there is a
             // one grid 
             // and 
             //two radio button that are subscribed on radio_btn_checked
             //

                BoxActionPlayer boxAction = new BoxActionPlayer(stringHere);
                grid1.Children.Add(boxAction.stkPanel);
                Grid.SetColumn(boxAction.stkPanel, 2);
                // Grid.SetRow(boxAction.stkPanel, 1);
                // this.Show();
                boxAction = new BoxActionPlayer(stringHere());
                grid1.Children.Add(boxAction.stkPanel);
                Grid.SetColumn(boxAction.stkPanel, 3);
                ..
                ..
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private void Radio_btn_checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var button = sender as RadioButton;
            MessageBox.Show(button.GroupName + " " + button.Content.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

How is possible to subscribe rdBtn1,rdBtn2,rdBtn3 in **BoxActionPlayer** *class* to *Radio_btn_checked* in Main Windows class even if they are in different classes ?

If is possible, i need more general tips :
Often in my programming style , I use the GUI part as a bridge.
I often have a class composed of many others(modeling objects ). This class has a "matryoshka" effect.(It contains the other)

I collect input data(by GUI)from Windows Main class and send it to the class that has a matrioska effec(inputs as parameters).

In general if I create other classes with windows components (like checkboxes, buttons and others..)

how should I handle the events in order to use them in the main class (public partial class MainWindow : Window) (as in the example above)
is there a better way? Ty.

In the example I need to dynamically create component  **BoxActionPlayer**(is a combination of label,txtbox and radiobutton) at runtime.IT depends on which option User chooses in the previous radiobutton.
With a particular user selection, I need to generate more BoxActionPlayer(combination of label,txtbox and radiobuttons)
But then I don't know how to handle the event from a different class (I need to retrieve the selection made by the user and use it in the main windows class.

excuse for my English.Ty

I have thought about creating a field in a BoxActionPlayer where i can store the user selection, then pass it by getter . but how i can notify  that the i have a new input parameter?

I need in each case to react to the event I don't know how to capture and pass to another class

Comment: It is not impossible to build a view only by code behind but it will be very onerous. I would recommend to host them in a `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`.

Comment: In WPF, it is accepted that the state of UI objects is completely determined by the current values of its properties. Therefore, the representation of a UI element must depend on the properties of the element. If you need some additional behavior, additional properties, then I think you need to use Custom Control.

Comment: You will separately set the necessary additional properties on Sharp, RoutedEvent, the behavior logic you need. And separately in the Default Theme (Themes/Generic.xaml), set your element's Template to render it. Parent elements (such as a window) should not listen to nested UI element events, but to the properties and RoutedEvent of your element.